# Unable to show a PopupWindow above soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a method in PopupWindow:

```
public void showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)
```

On most of device, I can place a PopupWindow at bottom of screen, even the keyboard is open, like this:

```
showAtLocation( rootView, Gravity.Bottom, 0, 0 )
```

But there are exceptions on some of device, 
such as Xperia Z1 comapct, ASUS Zenfone 5.
The available space of PopupWindow is restricted. (outside of keyboard)

Does anybody facing the same issue?
Or any suggestion?

Comment: Probably you'll have to close keyboard before showing the popup.

Comment: But showing popup above keyboard is my main purpose.

Comment: try using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: I'm having the same issue! It works fine on Samsung S4 but it shows on top of keyboard on Samsung S2!

Answer (score -1):

Add these two input modes on your `PopupWindow`:

```
popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite soft input mode? Only last line works.

Comment: the first line should call to : setInputMethodMode